# Why my code gives a different output when zero is added front?

Tags: bit

can anyone explain why the output is 65?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int b=0101;
        printf("%d",b);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because 0101 is an octal number (it is in base 8). In C octal numbers start with 0. So it is 64 * 1 + 8 * 0 + 1 * 1 = 65.

Comment: Exactly. "Octal" is base-8 and includes the numbers 0-7.  And `0x` would indicate a *hexadecimal* number, base-16 with digits 0-9, A-F.  A digit in octal representation is three bits long; in hexadecimal, four bits long.